# Is there any index which relates population growth rate with food production growth rate?

Tags: economic-growth, agriculture, population-economics

I would like to know if there is an index which shows if food production growth is keeping pace with population growth worldwide. I know there are population growth rates available, for example for population there is a figure of 30% population growth rate for the period 1990-2010 worldwide from UN. Food production is harder to find , so I'm not sure if they are well known. I found here
[Food production growth](http://www.deltafarmpress.com/management/food-production-growth-not-keeping-pace) that USDA economists estimate global agricultural TFP growth averaged 1.4 percent per year between 2000 and 2007, but that doesn't help to compare it with the 1990-2010 period of population growth. So, is there any organization which keeps track of both figures or makes an index to compare both food production growth worldwide with population growth worldwide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://ourworldindata.org/food-per-person/) there is a very good summary of existing information. Key variables are daily intake of calories/proteins/fat per person (so it is not so much about tons of food but their nutrient content). An example:

[image]

Notice that most of the data is taken from the FAO, which is available online [here](http://www.fao.org/faostat/en/#data).

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the components of [Global Food Security Index](http://foodsecurityindex.eiu.com). If I'm not mistaken, you can actually download the data free online from the same website. It covers a large set of countries globally.